# What tense do you use in this case?

Tags: tense, past-tense

Context: you're talking with the person and he's saying some new info for you.
How would you answer?

1. I didn't know this. (Past Simple)
2. I hadn't known this. (Past Perfect)

For me the second is more correct because it's about my previous status and not about my previous action.

Comment: Is there a rule about a previous status and not a previous action?

Answer (score 2):

You would use past perfect when you are talking about some action or state that was complete at the time you are talking about.

> When I arrived at work yesterday, I'd hadn't heard about the redundancies.

That's not the case here.  You are talking about a state that is in the past. So just use past tense

> I didn't know that.

You almost never use "I hadn't known" because "knowing" is never completed in the past.

("That", not "this")